# Графический тулкит для IceVM  или Openbox

Tags: linux

Всем ку!

В процессе изучения мира Линукса, а в частности названных выше оконным менеджеров - которые, судя по прочитанному, некоторые используют в качестве полноценных сред/окружений раб. стола - задался таким вопросом - какие тулкиты используются для создания прикладных программ?

Или все-таки используется GTK/Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном, да